# How to Compare two properties and then sort

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of strings in order I've set manually `"1" "2" "5" "4" "3"` etc.. I also have another class tied to a number of elements which contains various properties, one of which is an int `OrderString`

How do I re-arrange the order of the objects according to my list of strings.

```
list<string> L_string = new string { "1" "2" "4" "3" "5" "6" "7"}
```

Also a list of Items the that properties such as Name, Number, Date attached to them.

Assuming l_Item inherits from Products

> var SortedMan =
>   l_Item.OrderBy(o=>o.number.ToString()).CompareTo(L_string)));
>   Something like that, but an actual working code.

So basically the amount of items in both will be the same. I need it to re arrange list of Items in order of how they are inside the L_string.

Comment: Give a code example of the other list, because I don't quite understand.

Comment: So not clear and that syntax for list<string> L_string is not valid

Comment: So the question is how to sort Products list based on order provided in other list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this GenericComparer class](https://gist.github.com/pmcfernandes/7acdb6a799b8704f54b3186b7e75f236) implementation.

Use somehting like this

```
Array.Sort(YourArray, new GenericComparer());
```

Or use

```
Array.Sort(YourArray, new PropertyDescriptorComparer());
```

for property of class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I_Item is a List<Product>:

```
var sortedList = new List<Product>();
foreach (var value in L_string)
{
    sortedList.AddRange(I_Item.Where(x => x.number.ToString() == value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that entries in L_string actually correspond to items in l_item, you can do something like this:

```
var sorted = l_item
    .Where(item => L_string.Contains(item.number.ToString()))
    .OrderBy(item => L_string.IndexOf(item.number.ToString()));
```

The `Where` method filters the collection and returns a new collection with all matching elements. `OrderBy` reorders the collection based on the item's index in the `L_string` collection.